# Dual-head with fluxbox

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr, fluxbox

I have a laptop with fluxbox as window manager, and I'm trying to configure the dual-head behaviour, for when I connect a video-projector.

My system is AMD-optimus based, but I mainly only use the Intel integrated GPU.
I'm running fluxbox on gentoo.

I can pretty well set everything up with `arandr`, as clone or extended desktop, yet there are some points pretty annoying :

- When in extended desktop mode, the two screens are not considered as distinct at all by fluxbox : maximised application take the whole space of both screens and the fluxbox taskbar extends to the whole width of the big virtual screen.
- When in clone mode, some applications (my shell `urxvt` mainly) see their window border completely disappear.

Is there a way to configure fluxbox to fix theses ?

Comment: have you compiled fluxbox yourself? is fluxbox supporting the XINERAMA extension? `$> fluxbox -info | grep -i xinerama`

Comment: @akira I actually don't have anything compiled with XINERAMA support, I believed it was somehow outdated against RANDR. Do I need to switch to a XINERAMA-based system to have a working dual-head ?

Comment: yes. at least fluxbox needs it to detect the screen-layout.

Comment: @akira Ok, I did a lot of tests. Indeed, the XINERAMA useflag helps for screen-layout, thanks. Yet the border problem seems completely unrelated. Looks like a fluxbox bug...